# Executing node script in a python script inside Google Cloud SDK

Tags: python, node.js, google-app-engine

I am trying execute a node.js script inside python code running in Google App Engine. Something like this below:

```
from Naked.toolshed.shell import muterun_js

def foo(parameter):
    response_from_js = muterun_js('./views/api/generateSignedTransaction.js',
                                  parameter)
    response = response_from_js.stdout
```

But `Naked` cannot be used inside GAE because of its [dependencies on C](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27) and inbuilt libraries like `subprocess.call()`, `subprocess.check_output()` and `os.system()` did not work as well  I am guessing due to the same reasons as they execute system calls they would have C dependanices. Is there any alternative to passing parameters and executing the node.js script which would work in GAE?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, depending on what `generateSignedTransaction.js` does, you can create a Google Cloud Function with your JS script, then, just call it from your Python.